# Unable to get responses in ACRA Crash report after first response

Tags: android, crash-reports

i have being using [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) ,which is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form.

**i have been using following code in OnCreate of Application**

```
 @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "XXXXXXX", mode=ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
         forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false,resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text) 

public class MyApplication extends Application{

      @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
            ACRA.init(this);
            super.onCreate();
}
}
```

When i First test it i got response in ACRA CrashReport form(In form of Google Doc) but for next time for same crash  i didnt get response whenever any crash/exception  occur in my android application.

Comment: Are you sure there was an Internet connection when the errors occured?If I remember correctly ACRA will save the error report on the device when it can't be sent and try again when the app is restarted, so you might want to check if there are error reports.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you set all permissions needed ACRA. It depends on fields that you want in report, some of them need READ_LOGS permission or READ_PHONE_STATE permission
(for more http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ReportContent)

If error still present and connected with report sending on Google Doc try to add custom timeout:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "xxxxxxxxx", socketTimeout = 25000)
```